# include comma as data in xml to csv conversion using xslt

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

Im trying to convert xml data to CSV. How do I add COMMA as data/text in CSV?
I couldn't use COMMA as separator since CSV is comma delimited file. Please help me to generate data as below:

```
rowId   data
1   [xValue,yValue,zValue]
2   [xValue,yValue,zValue]
```

Some sample data:

```
<parent>
<c1>
<c2 x=1 y=2 z=3>
</c2>
</c1>
</parent>
```

My present xsl extracting the xml data is :
Adding a COMMA as separator or text is delimiting the data in file.
Please suggest the right way.

```
            <xsl:for-each select="childlevel1/childlevel2">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('','[')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@z"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(']','')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actual data has a comma in, which you don't want to treat as a delimiter, you need to put quote marks around that field.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:text>rowId,data&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="childlevel1/childlevel2">
        <xsl:number />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;[',@x,',',@y,',',@z,']&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

When you apply it to this XML

```
<parent>
    <childlevel1>
        <childlevel2 x="1" y="2" z="3" />
        <childlevel2 x="11" y="12" z="13" />
    </childlevel1>
</parent>
```

The following CSV is output

```
rowId,data
1,"[1,2,3]"
2,"[11,12,13]"
```

When you open this in your favourite Spreadsheet (like Microsoft Excel, or OpenOffice), it should only have two columns.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Tim. Your code works adding the comma as data, one last thing I need is, All the ChildLevel2 should go in one row like [[1,2,3],[11,12,13]]. Please help

Comment: It's probably best to ask a whole new question about that. Make sure you include a valid sample of your XML and your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: I have added it as new question. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593998/add-comma-as-delimiter-when-creating-array-of-arrays-as-one-field-in-csv-from-xm

Comment: Hi Tim, Can you please help with the above issue.