# Add comma as delimiter when creating array of arrays as one field in csv from xml data using xslt

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

My actual data is as follows :

```
<image name="101272.dcm">
<gobject type="Right"><polyline><vertex index="0" t="0.0" x="636.0" y="1920.0" z="0.0"/><vertex index="1" t="0.0" x="604.0" y="2296.0" z="0.0"/></polyline></gobject>
</image>
<image name="101280.dcm">
<gobject type="Right"><polyline><vertex index="0" t="0.0" x="1776.0" y="392.0" z="0.0"/><vertex index="1" t="0.0" x="1456.0" y="424.0" z="0.0"/></polyline></gobject>
</image>
```

I was successful in extracting all other data as required. But using the comma as delimiter is painful as Im a beginner in xslt.

Im using xslt version 2 and my code is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            seriesUID,annotationType,coordSys,data,name,label
            
        <xsl:for-each select="//gobject">
            <xsl:variable name="seriesUID" select="ancestor::image/@name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($seriesUID,'.dcm')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',','polygon')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@annotationType"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',','Image')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@coordSys"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',','[')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="polyline/vertex">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('','[')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@z"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(']','')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(']','',',')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',','')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',','&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generating below output :

```
seriesUID   annotationType  coordSys    data    name    label
1006780 polygon Image   **["[3476.0,1196.0,0.0],"[3436.0,1036.0,0.0],]** Right  
1006810 polygon Image   **["[3064.0,744.0,0.0],"[3300.0,912.0,0.0],]** Right
```

Please help me eliminate the double quote marks and the last COMMA in the field `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only use XSLT 2.0, then this is how you could do it...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>type,data,label&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//parent" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
    <xsl:text>,"[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="child1/child2/concat('[',@x,',',@y,',',@z,']')" separator="," />
    <xsl:text>]",hard coded&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: I am wondering if indeed you are using XSLT 2.0. Simply putting `version="2.0"` in a stylesheet won't achieve anything unless you have an XSLT processor that supports it.

If this is the case, here is an XSLT 1.0 version of the previous XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>type,data,label&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//parent" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
    <xsl:text>,"[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="child1/child2">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',@x,',',@y,',',@z,']')" />        
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]",hard coded&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should be able to adapt this to your new XML hopefully.

Note: To see what XSLT processor and version you actually have, see this question...

[How can I check which XSLT processor is being used in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Im getting the following error : line 13: Required attribute 'select' is missing.' at the line ---> <xsl:value-of select="child1/child2/concat('[',@x,',',@y,',',@z,']')" separator="," /> . Can you tell me why is that ?

Comment: Can you edit my XSLT to remove those quotes in my result data?

Comment: The above is the sample data I created as I couldn't add the actual data and requirement. It will help me a lot if we can remove the double quotes in my extracted data. Im stuck with this for a week now

Comment: I posted my actual data and full code. Please suggest

Comment: Please avoid making significant changes to your question after it has been answered. You need to make sure your question is truly representative of your actual problem to start with. I have, however, edited my answer with a final suggestion.

Comment: Hi, I have used the above code but it doesn't remove the extra double quotes and last comma : ["[1736.0,976.0,0.0],"[1752.0,1088.0,0.0],]. Please suggest

Comment: Are you sure you have used the above code? I test it at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQg using your actual input XML, and it works fine for me. Thanks

Comment: Or see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQg/1 for a more complete sample. Note that you have no `label` attribute in your XML, so the final field is empty

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. Im new to XSLT so I integrated your code in for loop of my code. But later I started off with adding my code to yours and it works awesome.